# can't install dbeaver on Virtual Machine following step based on link

Tags: linux, sudo, yum, dbeaver

I want to install dbeaver on virtual machine that using linux (maybe) following this step https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-dbeaver-on-ubuntu-debian/

i try to execute this code

```
wget -O - https://dbeaver.io/debs/dbeaver.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dbeaver.io/debs/dbeaver-ce /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dbeaver.list
```

but there is error occured that the apt-get command not found because the apt not installed.
I want to use another alternative code by using yum because my computer has installed it. But i dont know how to replace the code above?

so, anyone have any idea to install this software alternatively?

By the way i have installed postgreSQL server to use in dbeaver following this step https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-centos-7/ and it worked

thank in advance

Comment: Are you on an ubuntu machine? It looks like you are on an RPM based distro

Comment: Can you update your question? The title is misleading and irrelevant to the body. Also, doing a quick search using your favorite search engine yields a ton of results for this.

Comment: i dont understand about RPM or anything you said. I use Virtual Machine that i connect it through remote that i dont know about this VM

Comment: In that case you may want to do a read on https://linuxconfig.org/comparison-of-major-linux-package-management-systems before you paint yourself into a corner; either way, this is not a programming problem, voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following this guide: [Install and Configure dBeaver on Fedora CentOS](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-dbeaver-on-fedora-centos/), in particular this line is how they installed dbeaver and the gpg keys appeared to have been checked as a part of the installation process:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh ./dbeaver-ce-latest-stable.x86_64.rpm
```

Since it looks like with yum you don't need to manually add the key to your keychain like the debian instructions had you doing, the keys appear to be managed more automatically through RPM.

Here is a [description of how yum and rpm are related](https://askanydifference.com/difference-between-yum-and-rpm/) in particular:

> [Yum] mainly functions on RPM-based Linux systems and is dependent on RPM for performing its function but is also used for the management, installation and up-gradation of the packages in RPM-based Linux systems.

This also explains why people were commenting that it appears your VM is rpm based vs ubuntu/debian based.